# MySQL / PHP IF statement during while fetch array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display a pie chart that shows the results of my query. In this sample I have 3 time periods (Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner) and count how many records I have for each period. When displaying the chart though, I need to have each dataset with a different color, which is why I added an IF statement while fetching results.

Naturally, the statement is not working and only returns the color for "breakfast". How can I refresh the statement to check each returned row for the Period name and then echo the respective color?

Thanks

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $count = $row['period_count'];  
    $period = $row['period'];

    if ($period = "Breakfast") {
            $color = "#F38630";
        } elseif ($period = "Lunch") {
            $color = "#E0E4CC";
        } else {
            $color = "#69D2E7";
    }

    echo    "{"."\n";
    echo    "value : " . $row['period_count'] . ","."\n";
    echo    "color : \"" . $color ."\","."\n";
    echo    "label : \"" . $row['period']."\""."\n";
    echo    "},"."\n";

}
```

Comment: Your conditionals need the `==` operator. `if ($period == "Breakfast") {`

Comment: If you don't put double == it will assign the value of Breakfast to the variable of $period. If you do double (==) it compares them. Just wanted to add to larsAnders

Comment: took you guys a whole minute to figure this out, huh? ;) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out by @larsAnders, the == operator is needed to compare values.

Comment: If you're making a habit of messing these up, flip your terms. `"Breakfast" = $period` will cause an immediate error rather than silently do the wrong thing. Over time you'll be able to spot `=` mistakes from a mile away.

Comment: You guys are fast! Everything I think to say pops up before I get a chance to say it :)